# Print out list of files less than specified file size

Tags: command-line, files, scripting, ls, search

I'm trying to create a script that can be executed to search a list of files, compare the file size field to the specified file size, and then display the files that are less than the specified file size.

I understand that I must use 'ls -l' in order to get a detailed list of files. However, how can I go about searching the list and pulling the files?

Comment: [do not parse `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score 8):

Your approach is clumsy (and fair to say *wrong*). There are dedicated tools for these sort of tasks, `find` is one of those.

For example, to find all files in the current directory that are less than 1 MiB (1048576 Bytes), recursively:

```
find . -type f -size -1048576c
```

Or with shells that provide such size based glob qualifiers e.g. `zsh`, recursively:

```
print -rl -- **/*(.L-1048576)
```

Here, contrary to `find` above, without the hidden files. Add the `D` glob qualifier to include them.

Comment: Note that at least GNU find rounds the size up to full units before applying the less-than test if you give a test like `-size -1M`. Meaning that it will only match files that have a size of zero, unlike `-size -1048576c` which will match files smaller than a (binary) megabyte.

Comment: @JVAN, for assignments, I suggest writing a solution with the given assumptions and requirements, and then writing an example input that blows up spectacularly showing those assumptions horribly invalid. And mentioning the fact that you're doing an assignment and forced to use improper tools if you happen to ask on SE...

Answer (score 3):

Things to bear in mind with parsing the output of `ls -l`:

- the format depends on the locale. The format is only specified by POSIX in the POSIX/C locale and even then it allows some variations (like the amount of spacing between the fields, the width of the first field...). For instance, you can't easily detect portably file names that start with blank characters.
- Many systems allow blanks in user and group names, making parsing the output reliably almost impossible there. Best is to use `ls -n` (to use numeric user ids) instead of `ls -l`.
- It's impossible to parse the output of `ls` reliably if the file names may contain newline characters (and newline is allowed in a filename in virtually all POSIX systems) unless you use the `-q` option (but then you can't tell the exact file name, just see a quoted representation from which you can't get back to the original file name) or use non-standard options found in some implementations. Though see also the trick below.
- The *size* field is not provided for all types of files (and the meaning of the *size* field varies between systems for some types of files). You'd probably want to limit to regular files.
- The above is assuming a POSIX `ls`. Old versions have been known to have different output formats, or missing blanks between fields under some circumstances...

So, with that in mind, provided you can guarantee that file names don't contain newline characters and don't start with blank characters, to list the regular files whose size is strictly less than 1MiB, you could do:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  ls -n | awk '
    /^-/ && $5 < 1048576 { 
      gsub(/([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){8}/, "")
      print
    }'
)
```

Add the `-a` option if you want to include hidden files. Add `-L` if for symlinks, you want to consider the file they (eventually) resolve to.

As other have said, the correct solution would be to use `find` here.

#### Trick to avoid the newline and leading blank issue.

If instead of `ls -n`, we use `ls -nd ./*`, we would be able to know where the file name begins (on `./`) and on what line it ends (on the line before the next `./`), so you could do:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  ls -nd ./* | awk '
    /\// {
      selected = (/^-/ && $5 < 1048576)
      sub(/.*\//, "./")
    }
    selected'
)
```

However note that it won't work if there's a large number of files in the current directory as the `./*` is expanded by the shell, and that could cause the limit on the number of arguments to be reached.

To include hidden files, `-a` won't help here, we'd need to tell the shell to expand them. POSIXly, it's a bit unwieldy:

```
ls -dn ./..?* ./.[!.]* ./*
```

(which is likely to cause warning messages about missing `./..?*` or `./.[!.]*` files).

Comment: @RakeshSharma, that would assume there's only one blank character between the date and the filename which POSIX doesn't guarantee. Note that `perl`'s `\s` is more like `[[:space:]]`. See `\h` for blanks only.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, the difference between `\h` and `\s` is not only `\n`. It's all the vertical spacing ones (vertical tab, form feed, carriage return at least). Those would not be used in the field separators by `ls`, so matching on them is unneeded. Only space and tab (in the C locale) are needed. In practice, `ls` implementations use spaces and no tabs, but POSIX doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: @S.C.: Oh ok got that. Thanks. That's being really paranoid ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to parse `ls's` output then you can find the `regular files` that are lesser in size than an upper-limit (`MAX bytes`) and `ASSUMING` no whitespace/newlines in your filenames you could do the following:

```
/bin/ls -l | awk -v MAX=150 '/^-/ && $5 <= MAX { print $NF }'
```